# Keeing database blob in sync with frequently changing domain model structure

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am working on a project that saves content to db as a json blob. We use jackson to serialize and deserialize this json. We are trying to architect the application so that these blobs can be saved forever and be retrievable.

Now the trouble. The model object structure is quite deep ( 100 - 150 classes) and it is prone frequent changes. When the object model changes, jackson will complain when asked to deserialize an older version of a blob stored in db.

I am looking for way so this doesn't happen. Has anybody come across a similar issue. Any thoughts and ideas will be helpful.

P.S.
There isn't any code in this as it is a design question. So, hopefully this won't get rejected.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2006/jw-0227-control.html

Looks like this answered this in excruciating detail already. Any additions to this are greatly appreciated.